# Wharton Research Data Service - Need to query/download comScore dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm currently doing a project in university which involves analysing passenger behaviour in the airline industry.

I am seeking clickstream data for airlines, who I have contacted but to no avail.

I have identified the comScore dataset on [wharton](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/index.cfm?) as being suitable for the study and alas I have no access.

If any kind soul could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated. Or if anybody know of any airline clickstream datasets, please let me know.

Thanks In Advance, 
David

Comment: [Clickstream data](http://www.opentracker.net/article/clickstream-or-clickpath-analysis)? What does that have to do with *passenger behaviour in the airline industry*? Your question is very unclear, please [edit] it. What kind of data do you want, in what formats, and what is this Wharton/Comscore you are referring to (add links)?

Comment: maybe they want data from users on airline wifi?

Comment: airlines primarily conduct their business online and the comscore dataset on the service has clickstream data for users visiting travel sites. I want to use this to analyse their behaviour on looking at travel sites, end output would be a sankey diagram or similar and would use it to train the model i'm using in my research.  http://www.whartonwrds.com/